# Is rotating developers on a project a good or bad idea?

Tags: project-management, teamwork, team

I'm working on a small team that will begin working on a large new project with another small team. The other team is currently working on a legacy system that they have been working on for years.

The manager has decided that the developers from my team will be rotating every few months to replace developers working on the legacy system. That way the other team will have a chance to work on the new project and have a better understanding of the new system.

**I want to know the benefits and drawbacks (if any) of rotating the developers from the project every 2-3 months.**

I know that this is a similar question to ["Is rotating the lead developer a good or bad idea?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53747/8093), but that question focuses on a lead developer. This question is about rotating the entire team on and off the project (tech. lead for the new project may or may not be rotated -- I don't know yet).

Comment: There is a question about this at ProjectManagement StackExchange - [Do you know any companies that rotate developers between different projects on regular basis?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/do-you-know-any-companies-that-rotate-developers-between-different-projects-on-r)

Comment: I didn't wont to make this into subjective / argumentative question by giving my personal opinion in the question. My gut feeling is that this is not a good ide, but maybe there is something that I don't know about :)

Comment: What reason did the manager give when you asked him why? It's in a company's best interest to have shared knowledge about a product in case developers leave.

Comment: @user814064 Yes it's in the client's best interest if the "legacy" team is working on the new project.

Comment: Is the new system intended to replace the legacy system?

Comment: @DanNeely not directly (but the legacy system will probably be rewritten in the future). However they will most likely communicate through some kind of API on.

Comment: @Aaronaught I'm not actually sure if the entire team or only a part of the team will be rotating.

Comment: That's a problem. If your management is not already being completely transparent about this then it's probably a sign that they haven't thought it through at all.

Comment: What I would suggest is that you make the intital team that starts the project composed of some current legacy devlopers and some current new project devlopers. Keep them through the porject. At the end the lagacy devlopers support the new product and the new devlopers join some other legacy developers to do the next project. That way the team is teh same through the project (Or major release) but legacy people get up to speed on what they will be supporting later. New hires shoudl generally start on legaacy unless they have some special skill you team doesn;t havea nd needs for the project.

Comment: This "Rotation" sounds like a clever way for managers to make  developers do painful work on the legacy system without paying them any extra (as they should be doing. Cobol and SharePoint developers make good money, but they can have it).

Comment: 2-3 months is WAY too short for anything non trivial.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I'm surprised that everybody thinks this is such a good thing. The authors of [*Peopleware*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633439) (which, IMO, is still one of the precious few software project management books actually worth reading) strongly disagree. Almost the entire Part IV of the book is dedicated to this very issue.

The software *team* is an incredibly important functional unit. Teams need to jell to become really productive. It takes time (a *lot* of time) for team members to earn each others' respect, to learn each others' habits and quirks and strengths and weaknesses.

Certainly, from personal experience, I can say that after a year of working with certain people, I've learned to laugh off certain things that used to rile me up, my estimates as team lead are much better, and it's not too difficult to get the work distributed so as to make everyone happy. It wasn't like that in the beginning.

Now you might say, "Oh, but we're not breaking up the whole team, just moving a few people." But consider (a) how blindly unproductive their *replacements* are going to be in the beginning, and (b) how many times you'll find yourself or other teams saying, without even thinking, *"I really liked X"* or *"This would have been easier with Y still around"*, subtly and unconsciously offending the new members and creating schisms within the existing team, even sowing discontent among the "old" members.

People don't do this *on purpose*, of course, but it happens almost every time. People do it without thinking. And if they force themselves not to, they end up focusing on the issue even more, and are frustrated by the forced silence. Teams and even sub-teams will develop synergies that get lost when you screw around with the structure. The *Peopleware* authors call it a form of "teamicide".

That being said, even though rotating *team members* is a horrible practice, rotating **teams themselves** is perfectly fine. Although well-run software companies should have some concept of product ownership, it's not nearly as disruptive to a team to move that entire team to a different project, as long as the team actually gets to finish the old project or at least bring it to a level they're happy with.

By having *team* stints instead of *developer* stints, you get all the same benefits you would expect to get with rotating developers (documentation, "cross-pollination", etc.) without any of the nasty side-effects on each team as a unit. To those who don't really understand management, it may seem less productive, but rest assured that the productivity lost by splitting up the team totally dwarfs the productivity lost by moving that team to a different project.

**P.S.** In your footnote you mention that the tech lead might be the *only* person *not* to be rotated. This is pretty much guaranteed to mess up *both* teams. The tech lead is a leader, not a manager, he or she has to earn the respect of the team, and is not simply granted authority by higher levels of management. Putting an entire team under the direction of a new lead whom they've never worked with and who is very likely to have different ideas about things like architecture, usability, code organization, estimation... well, it's going to be stressful as hell for the lead trying to build credibility and very unproductive for the team members who start to lose cohesion in the absence of their old lead. Sometimes companies *have* to do this, i.e. if the lead quits or gets promoted, but doing it by *choice* sounds insane.

Comment: Don't disagree entirely - however its not without its flaws - Teams can and do built empires, sometimes these crumble Productivity is not always the most important aim of a manger, who (if any good), is looking more towards the end game than other might be.

Comment: @mattnz: What "end game" is there for a manager other than high productivity, employee retention, and being able to ship on time/on budget? I'm talking about *ethical* managers here of course, who genuinely want to do what's best for the company and aren't using the team or project as a vehicle to further their own personal career goals. A software organization *wants* empires - empires are stable and make money - and yes, empires can fall, but they're far less likely to fall than a house of cards.

Comment: Its an irresponsible management that allows an empire to to build to the extent the inmates run the asylum....this is a discussion about programmers, I concede you point....

Comment: rotation is better than folks leaving the company entirely

Comment: @warren: If those two options are your only ones, then the latter is almost inevitable.

Comment: @Aaronaught - true; however, exposure to all of a company's assets ("legacy" (which has so many definitions and uses, it's turned into a generic like "kleenex" for tissue) is just as important as whatever is "new") will make individuals better contributors. Rotating folks in and out every couple months is probably not helpful at all ... but rotating in general is a good idea

Comment: I seriously don't understand this answer at all. Everybody on a team should be a professional and work well with others assuming all team members are actually competent which is a different problem. Rotating team members is often the only choice for a manager that is chronically understaffed in both products or where attrition poses a serious threat. It is often very hard to find good talent in the first place. Rotating team members is a way to hedge bets against the developers leaving. It is also more equitable to devs working on legacy software when they would like to learn something new.

Comment: @maple_shaft: If you're understaffed, your projects will be late. Rotating developers (AKA multitasking on an organizational level) will only make the project **slower**. That's an indisputable, first-law-of-thermodynamics (figuratively speaking) fact, as you incur all of the same dev time *plus* all of the context-switching time. Speaking as both a developer and team lead, "hedging bets" is a very weak argument generally used to mask serious management and morale problems. And as for being equitable and the legacy software issue, didn't I already address that under "rotate teams instead"?

Comment: @maple_shaft: Bottom line, your comment implies belief in almost all of the myths I'm trying to dispel: (1) that people are loyal to the business rather than to their team; (2) that the subjective ideal of professionalism can somehow eliminate emotional responses; (3) that workers are just as productive or even more productive when multitasking (or task-switching); and (4) that knowledge workers can be effectively managed as interchangeable parts in a machine. All of these assumptions are not only false, but extremely dangerous.

Comment: @Aaronaught I can admit that I might be completely wrong, but this is after all the only types of organizations I have ever had the opportunity to work at in my entire career.  Perhaps I have grown emotionally numb?  Perhaps I am perpetually in bad morale so operating in bad morale has affected my bottom line?  I can see the value in rotating teams instead though.

Comment: @maple_shaft: To be fair, *most* organizations probably make the same assumptions and act exactly as you describe. However, *most* organizations are also steeped in MBOs and other antiquated management ideas that were debunked back in the 1960s. It takes conventional wisdom a long time to catch up to science (in this case economics and psychology). There *are* more progressive organizations out there, although *how much* more is often not entirely clear. Still, I'm answering based on what the current body of evidence says *should be* done, not what the common practice happens to be.

Answer (score 18):

I don't see much of a downside here myself. The rotation gets you:

- Cross pollination of institutional knowlege -- everyone will know the legacy project and the new one, at least in theory.
- Cross training -- different projects require different things often. You grow much more as a developer working in ugly, legacy projects than in nice, clean greenfield projects.
- Fundamentally better projects -- nothing like having a new team coming in to make you finish documentation and clean up ugly processes you are willing to live with but not publicly admit to.
- Better code -- more heads are better in most cases.
- Likely morale improvements -- variety is the spice of life. And who wants to be stuck in legacy project bug fixing / duct taping mode permanently. Also keep in mind your "new" project will become legacy at some point, do you want to be stuck there forever?

Probably the only downside is the productivity drop you get from switching places but that should only hurt bad the first go round. Afterwards both sides will have some seat time in both places and the ugly parts of the handoff will probably be better understood and perhaps solved.

Comment: I don't see how my morale would be improved if I got "demoted" to work on the legacy system.

Comment: A couple of disadvantages are in initial development time going up and the specific other tasks of the legacy team getting lower priorities.

Comment: Telastyn might have hit on the answer. Maybe people are acting like there are Upper and Lower class developers -- that can't be good for morale.

Comment: I agree with Telastyn. Idea to work with old technology, undocumented and coupled code, with probably no no real documentation, sounds like demotion. Maybe the business reasons for this are valid, but as a developer I'm not happy with that.

Comment: @Telastyn -- fair point but if you are rotating then you know you aren't stuck in the legacy project will rotate back out. Same way you rotate infantry regiments into and out of the front line.

Comment: @WyattBarnett - sure, it means I can coast for 2-3 months and any bugs I might create (or work I don't get done) can get passed on to other schmucks. And in my experience, the benefits of cross pollenation isn't worth the disruption of ever changing team dynamics.

Comment: @Telastyn If my old company had rotated out of legacy work I'd still be working there. Sure it sucks to get rotated on, but it sucks even more to know you'll never be rotated out simply because they need a legacy dev.

Comment: What do you mean?  There are upper and lower class developers.  That's life in any environment of more than a couple developers.

Comment: @Telastyn : or you could take the opportunity to learn and understand and perhaps improve the legacy system.

Comment: WyattBarnett - It depends. Mostly, different people will respond differently - which is why I do not favor some universal rotation mandate. People like @BeardedO will leave if stranded on the legacy project. Others will leave if rotated off of the interesting project. A catch-all policy seems like it would only cause issues.

Comment: @Telastyn and Christian and others: It is your problem if you see it as a demotion. Working on legacy systems is a challenge in and of itself that can give you incredibly invaluable experience to use to your advantage in green field development. Greenfield development really should have a lot less "cred" than it has as it is much much easier than trying to craft new features on an existing base even one without much technical debt. Brown field development is where you find the real craftsmen and women. Yes, you find them elsewhere too, but not the battle-field hardened ones.

Comment: @BBlake again your perception is precisely why a company would institute this philosophy. They want to be perceived as "fair" rather than assigning Good Work and Bad Work.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - Sorry, doing some maintenance work in Cobol isn't going to advance my career. Sure, the work might need done and it might even be valuable experience - but if my manager moves me to that full time, I will have my resume out ASAP. The fact of the matter is that some developers **will** perceive this as a demotion, regardless of what it really is. Balancing this perception with the desire to cross-pollenate isn't my problem, it's the manager's problem; that's their **job**.

Comment: I think it definitely would help if you started with the mandate that everyone does time on the "less fun" projects. Moving from the lap of luxury to the slums is not an easy transition.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - I didn't say that working on legacy systems can't be beneficial. I've worked on legacy systems in past - but in this particular case I think there isn't much to learn. Also, I've left out some additional details (about legacy proj.) that's not important for the question...

Comment: @Telastyn: lol if I were asked to work on Cobol now, yes I would leave in a hurry as well. I was assuming that both projects used the same or at the very least similar tech stack and mostly differed in brown versus green field scenario. (But, btw, your perception of legacy _is_ your problem if it keeps you from advancing to where you want to go).

Comment: I've tried for the most part to stay out of this argument, but one thing that I think people are missing is that if you have a good architect, and put honest effort into moving *off* the legacy system (i.e. by gradually building out replacement components), then most teams will automatically get experience with both the legacy system and the new code. You don't have to "assign" people to the legacy crap, it's just part and parcel of the product development. This does assume that you're working on either web development, SaaS, or corpware, rather than shrinkwrap - that's true for most devs.

Comment: @Telastyn I don't intend to be mean by saying this but that is an awfully selfish frame of mind.  Your colleagues have just as much a right to learn new technologies by jumping on a greenfield project. Do you really think those legacy devs wouldn't want that opportunity too?  You think it is your managers problem but that is intellectually lazy. Everything is your managers problem, even the unsolvable problems. They are trying to do the best they can with the **very real** constraints they have placed upon them.

Comment: @maple:A maintenance project developer and new system developer are usually 2 very different skillsets. Most developers can't do both very well because of the different skills that are necessary to learn to do either of the jobs well. While there is some overlap in skills and knowledge, they aren't the same job. Claiming the people are interchangeable is like claiming an auto mechanic can be moved between working on cars, motorcycle, airplane, boat and jet engines. In that case knowledge overlaps, but the reality is that doing so is a recipe for low productivity if not disaster.

Comment: @maple_shaft - sure, I'm just contrasting this answer which makes it sound as though rotation is nothing but benefit, regardless of the scenario. Many of those very real constraints are the personalities of the team.

Comment: Given that the 2 roles require different skillsets then it is most certainly a demotion/misfit to that developer who spends their time learning the ins and outs of software design and development to then be put on to a maintenance project. If the people on a maintenance project want to work on new development then they should fine tune their skills in software design and development and ask to be put on that type of project. Any good manager would match the skills of their people to the job. Putting someone who has honed his new development skills on a maintenance job is poor use of resources.

Comment: Unless the two projects are using nearly identical development stacks (which I sincerely doubt if one is a legacy project), I would not expect developers to get a morale improvement from switching.  Some developers don't mind bouncing around between technologies, but may are very particular about their toolchain and languages and get easily aggravated by arbitrary management changes to something they're comfortable with.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, in my experience we have often started our projects with this very intent. Down the line we have often failed to act on this intent due to constraints on the newer project and a belief that the cross training is too expensive.

I do always wish we had managed it though, as long term I believe it is beneficial to all parties - team, company, client & software. 2/3 months sounds like a long enough stint that there is limited risk of any serious negative impact, there is no context switching going on for the developers involved except at the changeover point at which time they can dedicate themselves to the alternative project.

A couple of possible benefits not mentioned:

- Better project management. If the project managers for both projects are on board then it is their best interests to work hard so that transition periods are not painful for either project. This is turn (depending on your setup) could yield tighter collaboration between the PMs and development teams.
- Better (proactive) documentation. If you know you're getting switched in and out of a project it is not only in the project's best interest, the companies best interest, best practice in general, but now in each developers own best interest to make life easy whilst they are bouncing around.
- The morale thing is a big deal, if your developers haven't had enough of being stuck on a legacy project, then they might not be the developers you want! If they have, switching them around and getting other developers to work on it will make them feel love for your company - they just might tidy up the bits of code they thought nobody would ever see as well. Legacy systems are often seen as second class projects which is often to their detriment, maybe this way you help change that perception to.

Comment: I think this is how it ends up in most companies.  Lofty goals, but the demands of rapid turnaround and minimal immediate cost avoidance usually precludes the cross-training and cross-development due to the lost productivity of bringing someone new up to speed on a project.

Comment: @BBlake Yes, unfortunately that is the case. Unfortunate, because it is very short-sighted and pretty high risk for a company to "restrict" knowledge of important systems to a lower number of people.

Comment: Unfortunately, most businesses, including the major worldwide bank I recently left to work elsewhere, are more interested in the bottom line for this project or week or budget cycle, than they are in planning ahead for the costs that will occur when a senior developer (such as myself) leaves.  With no budget for cross training on applications only I had advanced familiarity with.  Add the dozens of work hours wasted tracking down production problems that I could have solved in a couple hours because I knew the systems.  Shortsighted, but that's the corporate way.

Comment: @Marjan:I would be willing to bet that the costs incurred by having to do cross-training on a regular basis will be far, far higher than the costs of training a new hire as needed if someone leaves. Now, if an entire team leaves, then that's a different matter.

Comment: @Dunk: I don't know that it would. Cross training doesn't have to go as far as making the cross trained an expert in the field that isn't directly his/her own. It only needs to go as far as to ensure that the business wouldn't immediately be in a pickle and at risk of losing clients when the field experts leave causing the development in that field to grind to a halt. Nobody is irreplaceable, but business' do run risks when important knowledge or skills are restricted to very few people. And the costs of that risk becoming a reality can be very, very high indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Rotation is a good thing for the company, and can be a good thing for the developers too.

There are lots of good reasons and Wyatt has mentioned many of them in his answer.

That being said, in your situation, you may find when introducing this, the developers who are moving off the newer project onto the legacy project may well not be happy, so there needs to be very clear communication why this is happening and how long it is for, and the plan going forward.

It might be good to think about not swapping the teams wholesale to start and rotating 1 or 2 devs to start with, though this might seem like singling out people for a demotion (which some people may see it).

Comment: I like the idea of swapping just 1-2 devs to begin with. That will help reduce the initial negative impact on productivity.

Comment: You are dealing with software developers, not normal people. Software developers tend to be logical. They can't be as easily manipulated as the general public by incorporating ideas such as above. Other tricks are more effective on them, (e.g. bigger monitors, faster computers) but not political chicanery as this idea is trying to do. It will be a negative to those on the new development team, no matter what. Promises of rewards (ie. see above) is about the only way to cover up the bad taste. Of course, it'll be great (at first) for the maint guys, until they realize they aren't up for it.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Aaronaught that is very strange to see how many people just don't see downsides..
Few bad thinks, that you can point very quick - code doesn't have owner and when everyone is responsible for everything is not that good for quality. 
Developers aren't resources (even they are called like that very often by managers), they are people and for team is very important to know each other, rotation makes a bit chaos there.
If you work for some project for longer time you will became a expert (not only in domain, but in that project), you will know where most troubles came from, who will get you best answers or maybe some more specific domain knowledge's etc. If you are new, you will need to learn all this thinks, so it will slow progress.
But of course it's also good to know other practices in your organization, how other teams build and organize. It's especially good if your projects are related in some manner, for example one project is input for another (not necessary directly), so will get better understanding of big picture. And of course spreading expertise is good (if you will get time to get these knowledge's).

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Aaronaught's top answer and I have some additions.

- People do not like to be pushed around.
- In a hierarchical business setting, people may be assigned responsibilities that are later taken away from them again. This may just be part of the job. However, the more often this happens, the less likely will these people feel responsible for anything assigned to them.
- The former point also applies to maintenance work on things the people themselves did not create. Cleaning up other people's mess (or more neutrally formulated: unfinished work) is not particularly motivating to most creating individuals.
- The philosophy "a programmer is a programmer is a programmer, they are anonymous plug-ins to be inserted into projects as needed" does not make any programmer feel appreciated or care more about the tasks assigned to him.

The perfect time to reassign anyone is when they start to get bored with what they are doing. There is nothing more to gain, everything is under control, the job is done. In these cases they will typically come forward and ask for other opportunities themselves.

Of course reality is stubborn and often there is no choice, someone may be needed elsewhere because of whatever reason. This is not necessarily bad, it can also make a person feel important and if the person is to solve some big problem, there will be credit in it for him.

Just shuffling folks around to spread knowledge is likely to increase turnover. That way knowledge will be spread, but it will be spread outside the company which is probably not the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation of Programmers is good thing from company point of view and developer point of view.

**From a company perspective**

1. Management will get to know , the strength and weakness of particular developer whether they can handle multitasking or not and adaptive to changes .
2. If some developer leaves company for some reason , company already has backup ready for future.
3. It will enhance performance of project , as many people will work on it , same thing get tested by more and more developers. (Testing resource wastage minimized)
4. All team members works in team and it will boost performance of project and in future management will get to know , what kind of team needs to be made while implementing difficult module or task.

**From a developer perspective**

1. It will make developer more positive as his confidence increases.
2. Developers gets better and better ideas from others team mates code and they can use those technique in future development.
3. From better ideas and suggestions from other team members productivity of developer increases.

**Only one main thing , need to keep in mind that,**

Rotation of Programmers should not happen very frequent.
after 60% - 70% development done then only shifting will be beneficial.

Comment: I see a lot of bald assertions being made here. Some of them have almost nothing to do with rotation ("management will get to know the strength and weakness of particular developer"?), others are either awkwardly-phrased or just don't make sense ("all team members works in team and it will boost performance of project"?). What are all of these points based on? Do you have a source? Is it personal experience? If so, *what* experience? Is your "company perspective" coming from experience as a manager or team lead? Have you really seen any of these things work in practice?

Comment: Most of these proposed benefits really seem to be related to simply *being on a team* as opposed to being *rotated between teams*...

Comment: first one "Management will get to know , the strength and weakness of particular developer." is actually opposite, because it's much easier to hide your weaknesses when you are moving from one place to another, there's always more people/software to blame, why it was late, buggy, not done.

Comment: There's no way in h... that project performance won't be very negatively impacted. Why on earth would you believe a project's performance would be "enhanced"?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** *Make it one team and then it's one team supporting 2 projects.*

To echo @Aaronaught I think mixing teams can be problematic as it may take time to acclimate to new practices, processes, etc.  If you rotate too many people to quickly the team will lose it's identity.  This leads to more questions, confusion and time spent trying to make up for that identity.

On the other hand if there is a concerted effort to join the 2 teams into one team and have 1 team support 2 projects I think that works great as long as the team isn't too big.  I have been part of numerous teams which support multiple projects.  The closer in technology the 2 projects are, the easier the transition.  In my experience the higher cost in transitioning from one project to another comes when crossing languages, client/server (GUI especially), industry (medical, web, game), or other similar lines.  The trick is get different people to work on the project frequently enough to gain the benefits, but not so often that the transition cost exceeds the benefits.

Then benefits to getting more people on a project is fairly well known, as are the costs.

Comment: "As long as the team isn't too big" is key here, I think; if each team has 10 people on it, a team of 20 people is most likely too big. Also, if there's any *physical separation* between teams (the OP doesn't specify) then it won't function as a single team and will make things more disorganized. This definitely *could* work, but it depends on the situation (can the teams be merged effectively) and also the management's goals (merging is more-or-less permanent, it will add more resources but won't accomplish the same ends as a project rotation).